# Generate an array of  0 - i chars

Tags: .net, unicode, char

I am trying to generate an array of chars using the '\u...' syntax. The purpose is to let the user select which characters they want to filter out of some string. This is what I have so far"

```
char[] uChars = new char[1000];
uChars[0] = '\u00e4';
Debug.WriteLine(uChars[0] + " " + Convert.ToUInt16(uChars[0]).ToString("X4"));

for (UInt16 i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " + i.ToString("X4"));
    Debug.WriteLine(@"'\u" + i.ToString("X4") + @"'");
    // the following line fails syntax but that is what I want to do.
    uChars[0] = @"'\u" + i.ToString("X4") + @"'";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methinks you want to be using [Convert.ToChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbhkhhc2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Man did I make that harder than it needed to be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `\uxxxx` syntax in string and character literals.

To do what you want, try casting to char instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    uChars[0] = (char)i;
}
```

Comment: I think the other was first so gave it the check.  But both answers correct.  Thanks